# Cross subscription follower ADX cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Can an ADX cluster have a follower database pointing to another ADX cluster that resides in a different Azure subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the clusters can be in different subscriptions, the relevant related limitation is that the two clusters must be in the same region, see the 
 [limitation section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/follower#limitations) in the follower database docs.